# application:openFile: doesn't get called at launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am working om my first Mac app, and it goes great. Except for one problem. 
My app uses PNG images to create new images, one can drag in his/her PNG image to a box and it shows the NSOpenPanel to chose a save location.

However, when I quit the application and right-click the PNG image and choose my app, the NSOpenPanel is not shown.
If the app is active and I do the same.. no problem.. it shows the NSOpenPanel and it does whatever it needs to do with the images. Just not at launch.

My question: Why not?

My code:
AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost/%@", filename]];

    [_infoLabel setTitleWithMnemonic:NSLocalizedString(@"Drag SOMETHING SOMETING here!", @"AppDelegate")]; // Debug text

    BOOL returnValue = [Resizer loadFilename:fileURL];

    if (returnValue)
    {
        [_dragDrop setImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename]];
    }

    return returnValue;
}

- (void)didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:(NSImage *)image
{
    [Resizer selectDestinationPath];
}
```

Resizer class:

```
+ (BOOL)loadFilename:(NSURL *)pathToFile
{
    _sourcePath = pathToFile;

    if ([self sourceFileIsValid])
    {
        [self didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_sourcePath]];
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        _sourcePath = nil;
        return FALSE;
    }
}

+ (void)selectDestinationPath
{
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(destinationSavePanelDidClose:)
                                                 name:NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification
                                               object:_window];

    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [openDlg setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanSelectHiddenExtension:NO];

    [openDlg beginSheetModalForWindow:_window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            _destinationpath =  [[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can we see `AppDelegate.h` and `Resizer.h` please? Also, in `+[Resizer loadFilename:]` you call `[self didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:...]`, which would equate to `+[Resizer didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:]`: where is the implementation of that method (I guess I'm confused about why `AppDelegate` has a `-didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:` instance method and `Resizer` has a `+didLoadSourceImageSuccessfull:` class method)? Additionally, in the `Resizer` class, you are directly accessing `_sourcePath`, `_destinationpath`, and `_window` from within class methods; where are these defined?

Comment: You may want to consider a Document-based application, which handles most of this for you.  (I don't grok all of what you're doing, so I don't know if that's right for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you are trying to open the dialog *before* your `_window` is displayed or loaded.
Try to open the dialog in the method `-(void)awakeFromNib` of your window controller or app delegate, e.g.:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {  
    if (isFileSentToApplication) [Resizer selectDestinationPath];  
}
```

If your controller class is a subclass of `NSWindowController`, you can also do that in   `-(void)windowDidLoad`.